Failure to output promise rejection
When failing to update the database, I was hoping to catch that error, however I get a "Success: successfully changed Wallet Names" message. A throw within a Promise/Promise chain will automatically cause that Promise/Promise Chain to be rejected. So why doesn't invoking changeWalletName cause the catch method to execute?
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { changeWalletName } from '../../../utils/postgresQueries'

// Handles POST requests to /api
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const { walletNickNames, userId } = JSON.parse(req.body)
     
    changeWalletName({ walletNickNames, userId }).then(onFulfilled =>
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Success: successfully changed Wallet Names" })
    ).catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({ message: error }) 
    })

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "COULD NOT CHANGE WALLET NAME" })
  }
}

export async function changeWalletName({ walletNickNames, userId }) {
  try {
    // update db
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}


are you want to catch the error inside the changeWalletName function?

@Yuvaraj M yeah

You don't have to catch the error inside the async function and throwing the error inside then catching again in the main function.
We can resolve this by using single catch in main function and with await keyword
In async function remove the try/catch
export async function changeWalletName({ walletNickNames, userId }) {
  
    // update db logic 
  
}

and in main function add the await and remove the async function's catch
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const { walletNickNames, userId } = JSON.parse(req.body)
     
    await changeWalletName({ walletNickNames, userId }).then(onFulfilled =>
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Success: successfully changed Wallet Names" })
    ); // add await and remove catch

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "COULD NOT CHANGE WALLET NAME" })
  }
}


Looks like it had worked :)
